# How can I get the information about my package being delivered?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I need something like the following.

if ($order->has_status( 'delivered' )):

I want to add custom css class if the package was delivered to the customer.
I use WooCommerce with WooCommerce ShipStation Integration.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the instance of your order :

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Then you get the data :

```
$order_data = $order->get_data();


$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_version = $order_data['version'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
```

Now you have this :

```
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
```

Then you can apply your CSS.
Source : https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html

Comment: That will provide me with order status.
What I need is shipment status, the information provided by ShipStation.

Comment: ShipStation doesn't make your order statut change to "delivered" ?

Comment: I didn't see delivered order status as an option until I made custom one.